# Facebook login via iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I recently have a problem for my Facebook integration into my app.

I want the app to be able to ask for user to type in their username and password every time they want to connect to Facebook, I tried the example that comes in the Facebook SDK "switch User", but I still have some problems in integrating the function into my app.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Use FBLoginView it will display a Login Button for Logging in with FBSDK and during logout functionality in your product, write this: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; and then dipslay the FBLoginView so that it will allow user to relogin into your product.

Comment: @RenoJones - make that an answer

Comment: @ScottSelby - I was in a rush, thought I'd just pass a suggestion quickly. Made the above one as an answer :)

Comment: I was originally using FBLoginView, but I was unable to change the user once I have logged in, and I want it to allow different users to log in. I was think about using FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy to control the login user, but still have no clue how to use it correctly

Comment: Dude, Create a logout button in your application and in IBAction of that button, put the following line - [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; and After execution of above line, display the FBLoginView again, so when user taps on FBLoginView, it will again ask user to login. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. I finally solved the problem by creating a button and add a IBAction to perform the log in/out, and when user is trying to login, I open the session by using the FBSessionBehaviorForcingWebView, which will allow different users to log in since it asks user for email & password every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use FBLoginView it will display a Login Button for Logging in with FBSDK and during logout functionality in your product, write this: `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];` and then dipslay the FBLoginView so that it will allow user to relogin into your product.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering my question. I finally solved the problem by creating a button and add a IBAction to perform the log in/out, and when user is trying to login, I open the session by using the FBSessionBehaviorForcingWebView, which will allow different users to log in since it asks user for email & password every time.